# Push notification is works or not when there is no network in android device?

Tags: android, push-notification

In my android application , i use push notification .I had one if there is no network connection in my android device means .Then push notification works or not in my android device

Comment: no..your require network compulsory..i think..

Comment: Without `Internet` you cant receive push `Notification`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Internet Connection.

GCM clients receive notifications through a socket, which is handled by Google Services  to the Internet

Answer (score 1):

If the target device is not connected to the internet, then the GCM adds the Notifications to a pipeline to be delivered at a later stage. There are limitation on the pipeline size and the maximum time of un-connectivity, after which GCM aborts the pending GCM messages. But for a general case, this should do the needful.

Answer (score 0):

Without Internet you will not receive any notification from GCM. Till your connection is not there GCM fill store all notification for you and as soon as you got connected it will release its burrer